# python jdatetime show two months before instead of one month before for the last day of last month

Tags: python

This is my code:

```py
import jdatetime
now = jdatetime.datetime.now()
end = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
month = 12 if now.month == 1 else now.month - 1
year = now.year - 1 if now.month == 1 else now.year
first_day_of_last_month = now.replace(day=1, month=month, year=year)
last_day_of_last_month = first_day_of_last_month - jdatetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Until the `first_day_of_last_month`, it works fine and shows the last month's last day (it is 01/10/1402, month is 10), but the `last_day_of_last_month` shows the 30/09/1402 instead of 30/10/1402.

Expected output is:

```
first_day_of_last_month is `first_day_of_last_month`.
last_day_of_last_month is `last_day_of_last_month`.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code works correct, but you are asking it to do the wrong thing if that makes sense? If you have the "first_day_of_last_month" and you go back one day further, then you arrive indeed at the last day of 2 months ago. Perhaps change it into something like this?

```
first_day_of_current_month = first_day_of_last_month + jdatetime.timedelta(months=1)
last_day_of_last_month = first_day_of_current_month - jdatetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, `first_day_of_last_month.strftime("%y/%m/%d")` prints `02/10/01`, but `last_day_of_last_month` still shows `02/09/30`.

Comment: Also `timedelta` doesn't have `months` keyword.

Comment: Maybe this can help? "from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta" > I believe it has more options for manipulating dates, including adding months.

Comment: I need to convert Jalali date to Gregorian date , so that's why I use `jdatetime`.

Comment: How about using "first_day_of_current_month = now.replace(day=1)" (instead of the first line in the answer above). So, use the replace function to get the first day of the current month, so that we don't have to add or subtract any months. Then we just go one day back from first_day_of_current_month after that?